# Possible to add data-validate="x" to Safecracker form tag?

Tags: safecracker, add-on-development

I'm wanting to add a new parameter (data-validate="parsley") to the Safecracker form tag. I know this isn't possible out of the box but was wondering whether it was possible to write a simple(ish) extension that could do it?

If anyone can give me some pointers, I'm willing to have a go.

Cheers

Jim

Comment: I need an answer on this one too, so chiming in so I get updates if someone has a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created an extension that'll let you do it.
https://github.com/jazonv/SafeCracker-HTML5-Attributes

In addition to `data-foo="bar"`, it'll also lets you use `autocomplete="no"` and `novalidate="novalidate"`.

*(Inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/objectivehtml/2595553) by Objective HTML)*

<sub>Disclaimer:

I'm by no means a PHP/Add-on dev. I just wanted to 'have a go' too. Hopefully there's nothing wrong with it.

If any better-versed devs want to give it a once over, that'd be appreciated.</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much for this Jason. I had no idea that Justin Kimbrell had already done something similar that you were able to adapt. I've tested the extension now and can confirm that it works!

Comment: Open source at it's finest folks. Again, nice work on this Jason.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.